# Print key-value in JSON object in HTML with Django

Tags: python, html, json, django

I have a JSON object in string that looks like 

`'{"key1":"value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"}'`

I can use `json.loads` to make that into a JSON object, but when I try to print it in HTML, it prints the entire JSON object like

`{"key1":"value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"}`

my function looks like:

```
def jsonPretty(json_string):
    return json.loads(json_string)
```

and in HTML/Django:

```
{{kvpair|jsonLoadsPretty}}
```

However I want it to print

`key1 value1
key2 value2
key3 value3`

The format can vary a little, but I want each key-value pair to separate by a `\n`, and the brackets should be removed.

What would be the best way of doing this?

EDIT:

I'm using `{% with kvpair|jsonPretty as kvjson %}` before running a for loop with

```
{% for k, v in kvjson.items %}
    <p> {{k}} {{v}}</p>
```

and now it works fine. Thanks for @Andrey Shipilov 's help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{% for key, value in kvpair %}
    <p>{{ key }} {{ value }}</p>
{% endfor%}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Comment: the kvpair is a string, so I tried json.loads first before using that for loop. However it returns error: `TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse some characters: |{{kvpair||jsonLoadsPretty}}`

Comment: Make a JSON object from your string and then pass it to the template. Then you'll be able to do `{% for %}` on it.

Comment: I am using the jsonPretty function written above. My line in HTML now looks like `{% for k, v in kvpair|jsonPretty %}`. If i just output `k`, it gives me the keys, but outputting k,v somehow makes it a string again and returns the first 2 characters of the key.....

Comment: Try `{% for key, value in kvpair.items %}`

Comment: I set the result of that function to a variable first and the for loop worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

works {% for key, value in kvpair.**items** %}